# Repeat each value in SQL table n times with 1:n in different column

Tags: mysql, sql

Edited to add: not sure why table formatting isn't working, but here is the written example:

I have a simple SQL table (call it SIMPLE) with unique values

```
**VALUE**
1699
2349
2934
3100
```

I am looking to create 3 repeats of each value in column 'VALUE' and create a second column that has an index of 1:3 for each value.

Does anyone have a simple way of doing this?

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do this using unions:

```
SELECT value, 1 AS idx FROM yourTable UNION ALL
SELECT value, 2 FROM yourTable UNION ALL
SELECT value, 3 FROM yourTable
ORDER BY value, idx;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

The following is more performant than `union all`:

```
select t.value, n.n
from t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3) n;
```

Why?  The table only needs to be scanned once.  This is only an issue if the table is relatively large, but it is worth mentioning the more efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example in SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE X(a INT); INSERT INTO X VALUES (1699), (2349), (2934), (3100);
CREATE TABLE Y(b INT); INSERT INTO Y VALUES (1), (2), (3);
SELECT X.a, Y.b FROM X, Y ORDER BY 2, 1;
```